# Docker file builds correctly but fails to run

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, dockerfile

**$ docker image build -t python-blog .**

```
Step 1/5 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 005d2078bdfa

Step 2/5 : RUN apt-get update -y &&     apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7c1fdabcc215

Step 3/5 : ADD . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5e2784fac3bd

Step 4/5 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7d038ff8d993

Step 5/5 : CMD ["/usr/bin/python3","run.py"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 24f691d13886

Successfully built 24f691d13886
Successfully tagged python-blog:latest
```

**$ docker run -p 5000:5000 python-blog:latest**

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"/usr/bin/python3\": stat /usr/bin/python3: no such file or
>   directory": unknown. ERROr[0005] error waiting for container: context
>   canceled

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev

ADD . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["/usr/bin/python3","run.py"]
```

Comment: You likely want to install python3-pip and python3-dev and use pip3.

Comment: Thanks a ton, your changes worked @hmm

Answer (score 0):

Your Dockerfile, doesn't not specifically installs python3, ubuntu-16.04 by default selects python (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.11), that's why it fails to execute the CMD instruction which expects /usr/bin/python3  which does not exists.

you have to update your Dockerfile to specifically install python3 if you want to run your code with python3.